# Low Variable / Matrix Blank Screen

Tags: matrix, playa, low-variables, low

We have a Low Variable using Matrix with 3 columns.

Two columns are raw text and one is a playa list of channel entries.

All has been working fine, there were about 60 rows so far - all of a sudden when we go to manage the low variable to add more content we see a blank screen (attached)

The data that has been input is still there (can see it on the front end)

Not sure how to fix or trouble shoot this.

ee2.6.1 / lv 2.3.5 / Matrix 2.5.5

[image]

Comment: Before anything, I'd recommend updating everything to the latest version: LV 2.4.0, Matrix 2.5.10. Update Playa and EE itself, too, if you can.

Comment: I can't update - site is going live in two days. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors showing in Firebug?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you are hitting a JS error which will be logged in the console or a PHP memory issue which should show in the PHP error logs. If you aren't seeing anything in the PHP error logs, set $debug = 1 in the /system/index.php file and reload the problem page.